# What would be the best way to set up this type of many relationship?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a table for Vendors, States, and Cities. When you create a vendor you can select a state and a few cities.

Initially I was serializing the cities but it became difficult to search so I thought I would break it out.

So far what I was thinking is on my Vendor table I have

> vendor_location_id

and in my Vendor location table I will have

> vendor_id state_id city_id

Now when I create a Vendor I need a way for it to populate vendor_location_id, vendor_id, state_id , and city_id. Any ideas on how to best go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the vendor_id in the vendor location table, you don't need a vendor_location_id in the vendor table.

Heres how I would do it:

```
Vendors
• id
• name

Cities
• id
• name
• state_id

States
• id
• name

VendorCity
• id
• vendor_id
• city_id
```

then the relationships:

```
class Vendor extends \Eloquent {
    public function cities()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('City');
    }
}

class City extends \Eloquent {
    public function state()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('State');
    }

    public function vendors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Vendor');
    }
}
```

in terms of attaching them --

```
$city = City::find(1);
$vendor = Vendor::create(['name' => 'Vendor Name']);
$vendor->cities()->attach($city->id);
```